# Is it possible to store and retrieve data from MySQL database simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to upload a file where I'll be storing the name, link & size of the file. Then, I want to retrieve the link of the file so that I can read it & store the content of the file in the database after extracting it.

Is it possible to do this in a single PHP file? Right now when I upload the file, it stores the name, link & size of the file to the database. But in order to read the uploaded file, extract the content & store the content to the database, I have to reupload the same file again.

users.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
    <FirstName>Example 1</FirstName>
    <LastName>Example 2</LastName>
    <Phone>Example 3</Phone>
    <Address>Example 4</Address>
</user>
```

Below is the PHP script:

```
<?php

//report any error
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

//connect to database
include 'conn.php';

$ds = "/";
$storeFolder = 'uploads';


if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fname = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $ftype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fsize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $flink = 'http://localhost/aps/upload/' . rawurlencode($fname);

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($flink);

    $firstname = $xml->FirstName;
    $lastname = $xml->LastName;
    $phone = $xml->Phone;
    $address = $xml->Address;

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__) . $ds . $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

    $query = "INSERT INTO user_details (link, name, size, type, first_name, last_name, phone, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $flink, $fname, $fsize, $ftype, $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $address);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($link, $name, $size, $type, $first_name, $last_name, $phone, $address);


}

//Close statement
$stmt->close();

//Close connection
$conn->close();

?>
```

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: or at least explain how the file is being uploaded - what process you are using to handle the upload, pull the database-name, where are you putting the file (away from its temporary location on-upload), etc.

Comment: Whatever you put in the database via PHP is also immediately available to the PHP script .. so I think we need to see some code to walk you through how it works.

Comment: I added the codes. Hope someone can help. I've been stucked with this for quite some time before deciding to post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're downloading the file after it's uploaded, try loading the file after you do the move_uploaded_file... and you want the contents of $targetFile inserted into table user_details into field "file_data" try changing to

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
$xml = simplexml_load_file( $targetFile);

$firstname = $xml->FirstName;
$lastname = $xml->LastName;
$phone = $xml->Phone;
$address = $xml->Address;

$query = "INSERT INTO user_details (link, name, size, type, first_name, last_name, phone, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $flink, $fname, $fsize, $ftype, $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $address);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($link, $name, $size, $type, $first_name, $last_name, $phone, $address);
```

Comment: It doesn't work and this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to extract the elements from the XML file that I uploaded and insert them into the database. Anyway, instead of file_get_content, I do it like this : $xml = simplexml_load_file($targetFile); Ok this works thanks!

Comment: yeah... not sure where my idea that you wanted the raw file data in the database came from LOL, removed that part. Glad the useful part is working for you!